# Why don't HashBytes and MD5CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash match?

Tags: .net, t-sql, hash, md5

Can someone explain to me why don't T-SQL's

```
SELECT substring(master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(hashbytes('MD5', 'HelloWorld')), 3, 32)
```

and .NET's

```
Convert.ToBase64String(New System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("HelloWorld")))
```

return the same result?

Tsql returns `68e109f0f40ca72a15e05cc22786f8e6` and .net returns `aOEJ8PQMpyoV4FzCJ4b45g==`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .net one is base64, the T-SQL one is hex. They are different encodings.

The length of the output tells you that too because MD5 delivers 16 bytes (as per the T-SQL solution)

Comment: (The .NET one is Base64, SQL isn't)

Comment: And by the way Vnuk, you explicitly say '`Convert.ToBase64String`' so it shouldn't be that surprising?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are asking T-SQL to return the bytes HEX encoded while you tell .NET to return them Base64-encoded... that are very different encoding and do never match...